# Sending event arg to custom event handler function

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, webclient

I have a class which initiates a webclient object and has a `DownloadProgressChanged` and a `DownloadFileCompleted` event. A form can initiate this object and the download. The form can also stop the download if the user chooses to close out the form.

The `DownloadFileCompleted` event handler function also takes in a parameter, filename to raise an event, which the form class can then process. I read up on how to define such custom handler functions so my code looks as below :

```
AddHandler fileReader.DownloadFileCompleted, Sub(sender, e) download_complete(FileName)
AddHandler fileReader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Download_ProgressChanged
fileReader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(Address), ParentPath + FileName)

Private Sub download_complete(filename As String)
        RaiseEvent DownloadDone(filename)
        
End Sub
```

I noticed that when the user closes the form, the download is stopped but I still get a Download Complete Event (I have read that this would come with `e.Cancelled = True`)

My problem is that I want to send this information over when I raise the event of, so my `download_complete` Sub would read something like :

```
Private Sub download_complete(filename As String, e as AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            RaiseEvent DownloadDone(filename, "CANCELLED")

        Else
            RaiseEvent DownloadDone(filename, "COMPLETE")
        End If
        
End Sub
```

This way I would be able to handle the following processes well in the event handler method of the form. I am not able to find any documentation for the approach. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Event handlers should ALWAYS and ONLY have two parameters: `sender` is type `Object` and should be the object that raised the event and `e` should be type `EventArgs` or derived from it and contain ALL the data for the event. If you want to pass a file path to an event handler then it should be as a property of that `e` parameter. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response @jmcilhinney! I went through your blog and as I understand it, I need to create a custom event which inherits from the  EventArgs Class and then I can add some data to the new event class, which can be used when the event is raised. However in my case I need to use the ```DownloadFileCompleted``` event and I dont think I can add any data to this event manually.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is the sort of thing you need to do:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Public Event DownloadComplete As EventHandler(Of DownloadCompleteEventArgs)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim downloader As New WebClient

        AddHandler downloader.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf downloader_DownloadFileCompleted

        Dim sourceUri As New Uri("source address here")
        Dim destinationPath = "destination path here"

        downloader.DownloadFileAsync(sourceUri, destinationPath, destinationPath)
    End Sub

    Private Sub downloader_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim downloader = DirectCast(sender, WebClient)

        RemoveHandler downloader.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf downloader_DownloadFileCompleted

        Dim filePath = CStr(e.UserState)

        OnDownloadComplete(New DownloadCompleteEventArgs(filePath, e.Cancelled))
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnDownloadComplete(e As DownloadCompleteEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent DownloadComplete(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DownloadCompleteEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public ReadOnly Property FilePath As String

    Public ReadOnly Property IsCancelled As Boolean

    Public Sub New(filePath As String, isCancelled As Boolean)
        Me.FilePath = filePath
        Me.IsCancelled = isCancelled
    End Sub

End Class
```

You start by calling the overload of `DownloadFileAsync` that allows you to pass data in that you then get back in the `DownloadFileCompleted` event handler. In that event handler, you can then raise your own custom event with the information you want using the steps I outlined in my blog post.